# Laravel caching a query

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Short and simple question. The below works:

```
function something() {
    $this->load(['descriptions.expenses' => function ($q) use (&$transactions) {
        $transactions = $q->where('date', '>=', $this->user->startDate())->get();
    }]);

    return $transactions;
}
```

It returns all expenses as expected. When I cache it, like so:

```
function something() {
    return cache()->rememberForever('budget_expenses_' . auth()->user()->id, function () {
        $this->load(['descriptions.expenses' => function ($q) use (&$transactions) {
            $transactions = $q->where('date', '>=', $this->user->startDate())->get();
        }]);

        return $transactions;
    });
}
```

It immediately returns nothing. I am just curious as to why this is happening. The reason for caching it is because it's generating a lot of queries, obviously.

The following also works as expected:

```
function something() {
    return cache()->rememberForever('something_' . auth()->user()->id, function () {
        return auth()->user()->budgets()->get();
    });
}
```

The issue is that `return $transactions;` this does not seem to get cached, so calling the cached key later will simply return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the methods on `cache()` like `remember` or `rememberForever` are supposed to `cache the resulting data from the closure` not actually return that value, you will still need to access that key to retrieve the data, something like this:

```
cache()->rememberForever('budget_expenses_' . auth()->user()->id, function () {
    $transactions = /* Something */;

    $this->load(['descriptions.expenses' => function ($q) use (&$transactions) {
        $transactions = $q->where('date', '>=', $this->user->startDate())->get();
    }]);

    return $transactions;
});

return cache('budget_expenses_' . auth()->user()->id);
```

Comment: Makes sense seeing this now,at least I understand what is going "wrong" in this case. In other cases I do it like this, it works, but in this case, it does not return the actual `$transactions` like you said. Thanks for helping me clear that up :)

Comment: I have re-opened (or un-accepted) your answer for now, since it is still unclear to mewhy my example does not work. I thought I understood, but I don't, since my updated question shows an example that does work as I expect it.

Comment: This is just a wild guess but, since you are using `&` when passing parameter, it's maybe not able to combine `memory position` with `caching service` to actually insert the right element. A wild wild guess

Comment: I'm playing around with it now, and I think I figured it out. Since in my views I am actually getting the `expenses` for multiple `budgets`, the first returned `expenses` will be cached. And since for that particular `budget` it is `null`, it will display `null` for all the others as well... Stupid me :) Have to make the cache unique for each budget.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my caching was working after all, but I wasn't making them unique for each budget, which means, for every budget, all `expenses` were the same, since the first one got cached...